# JQM - Add image to collapsible header dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set for days of the week, with user's activities inside it that represented as a listview inside the collapsible-set.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="calCol" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right">

                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h1 id="day1Header">Sunday<img src="#" /></h1>
                    <ul id="day1" data-role="listview">
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h1>Monday</h1>
                    <ul id="day2" data-role="listview">
                    </ul>
                </div>
...
```

All the content for the user's activities i take from my database so i insert all my content dynamically like this:

```
var userActivitiesObj = JSON.parse(data.d);
        for (var i = 0; i < userActivitiesObj.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 0; j < userActivitiesObj[i].time.length; j++) {
                var listItem = "<li style='background-color: " + userActivitiesObj[i].hobColor + ";'>";
                listItem += userActivitiesObj[i].actName + " - " + userActivitiesObj[i].actAddress + " - ";
                listItem += userActivitiesObj[i].time[j].startTime + "-" + userActivitiesObj[i].time[j].endTime;
                listItem += " (" + userActivitiesObj[i].time[j].audiance + ")</li>";                    
                $("#day" + userActivitiesObj[i].time[j].day).append(listItem);
                $("#day" + userActivitiesObj[i].time[j].day).listview("refresh");                
            }

        }
```

One last thing that left for me to do is to add image of every activity to the header of that day.
When i have tried to do it in html, it worked flawlessly:

```
<h1 id="day1Header">Sunday<img src="#" /></h1>
```

but when trying to do it dynamically, it doesn't work correctly.
That what i have tried to do:

```
$("#day1Header").html($("#day1Header").html()+"<img src='#'");
```

and:

```
$("#day1Header").append("<img src='#'");
```

I know that i am missing here something like the .list("refresh") function, but i have no idea what is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile adds an anchor tag with class `ui-collapsible-heading-toggle` within the header and places the collapsible title there. So you can remove previous images and append the new image like this:

```
$("#day1Header .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle img").remove();
$("#day1Header .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").append('<img src="https://placeimg.com/44/22/tech" />');
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/YWLdzx)**

Comment: I would never guess it alone, works like a charm, thank you!